# Как создать несколько объектов с помощью цикла?

Tags: c#

Нужно сделать несколько объектов в массиве.
Например, если нажму на кнопку на полигоне, чтобы появилось 10 объектов.

Пытался сделать так, но не работает:

```
int[] impactObj = new int[10];

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int f = 0;
    PictureBox[] obj = new PictureBox[impactObj](); 
    for (int i = 0; i < impactObj.Count(); i++)
    {
        obj.Location = new Point(19, 69);
        f++;
    }
}
```

Comment: что именно не работает?

Comment: Ну, для начала это банально не компилируется - посмотрите на эту замечательную инициализацию массива `obj`, а также на просто превосходные попытки положить туда объекты совершенно левого класса. @jcmax, вы пробовали почитать какие-нибудь учебники, прежде чем начинать писать программы?

Comment: это я пример привел. Я незнаю как объявить pictureBox в массиве, чтобы им потом дать разные точки Point впределах полегона

Comment: То есть, не читали. Вот вам [список литературы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/5577), почитайте хотя бы первую книгу. Настолько грубые ошибки при работе с массивами наталкивают на мысль, что вам пока рановато заниматься визуальным программированием и стоит заполнить пробелы в фундаментальных понятиях.

Comment: у меня здесь синтаксические ошибки сделаны специально, чтобы мне объяснили как правильно определить массив визуальных объектов, а не тыкали в ошибки синтаксиса, я когдо копировал я видел, что VS ругается на PictureBox. Да вообщем я нашел в проектах у себя решение ==> Label[] mySt = new Label[n]; //Массив стикеров, И ему по mySt работаем . Так трудно было правильно ответить?

Answer (score 2):

интересно, а кто мешал написать правильно?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var obj = new PictureBox[10]; 
    for(int i=0;i<obj.Length;i++)
    {
        obj[i] = new PictureBox();
        obj[i].Location = new Point(19, 69);
    }
}
```

это если перефразировать ваш код

а можно использовать например гинерики

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var obj = new List<PictureBox>(); 
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        obj.Add(new PictureBox(){Location = new Point(19,69)});
    }
    // Нужен массив? пожалуйста:
    var arr = obj.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: попробую спасибо